# Unable to save screenshots in the designated path or attach the screen shot to extentreports in MAC

Tags: macos, selenium, screenshot, extentreports

I have tried many ways to take screenshot on test case failure but nothing works. unable to take a screenshot and attach it to extentreport in MAC os while using selenium.

```java
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult tr)
{
    logger=extent.createTest(tr.getName()); // create new entry in the report
    logger.log(Status.FAIL,MarkupHelper.createLabel(tr.getName(),ExtentColor.RED)); // send the passed information to the report with GREEN color highlighted
    String screenshotPath="./Stest-output/"+tr.getName()+".png";
    TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot)driver;
    File img =ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    File destination =new File(screenshotPath);
    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(img,destination);
        logger.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(img != null)
    {
        System.out.println("Screenshot is below:"+tr.getName());
        try {
            logger.info("Screenshot is below:" + logger.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath));
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

throws null pointer exception when trying to copy the image from source to destination.

Have all the methods available in stack overflow.

Comment: So the line `FileUtils.copyFile(img,destination);` is throwing a NullPointerException?

Comment: Yes and I have tried many ways to fix it but no use.

Comment: It must be the `img` variable. I can't imagine the `destination` variable is null since a constructor is going to return an object or throw an exception.

Comment: Are you missing write permissions in whatever folder the `img` file gets put in?

Comment: It is fixed now, I have i am able to get the screenshot and save it into desired folder i have put the logic in the base class and have called the method in listener class but unable to attach it into extent report html file

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to attach screenshot into extent report html because you forget to call `flush()` method that appends the report HTML file with all the tests result/screenshots. There must be at least one ended test for anything to be appended to the report.

Note: If `flush()` is called before any of the ended tests, no information will be appended to report.

```js
@AfterTest
public void tearDown() {
extent.flush();
```